# In insert statement of SQL i have an error?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I wrote this code to insert one paramater to my DataBase with name "Barezkk", and with table data, but when press submit I have an error

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO data(FulName) 
VALUES ( $_POST['in2'])
```

is the syntax of values error?

Answer (score 4):

You need to wrap your `$_POST` part really...

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO data(FulName) VALUES ({$_POST['in2']})");
```

And if that value is a string, you should do this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO data(FulName) VALUES ('{$_POST['in2']}')");
```

Or you could concatenate it:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO data(FulName) VALUES ('" . $_POST['in2'] . "')");
```

Comment: And escape the input before passing it to the DB. Use PDO or `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: think u dear friend . may ALLA Bless U .

Comment: if i wont to insert more than one variable like (name,age,salary,email,gender,stage and more...)
, at this time all the variable r not String but int flaut string ...
Are the syntax is true for all datatype ? ... Thanks For Respone me

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the qutations (single and double)

```
          mysql_query("INSERT INTO Persons (FulName)
           VALUES ('$_POST['in2']')");
```